# Python regex match until certain word after identation

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string or similar:

```
baz: bar
key: >
   lorem ipsum 1213 __ ^123   
   lorem ipsum

foo:bar
anotherkey: >
   lorem ipsum 1213 __ ^123   
   lorem ipsum
```

I am trying to build a REGEX which captures all values after a key followed by a `>` sign.

So for the above example, I want to match from `key` to `foo` (excluding) and then from `anotherkey` to the end. I managed to come up with a REGEX which does the job, but only if I know the name of `foo`:

```
\w+:\s>\n\s+[\S+\s+]+(?=foo)
```

But this is not really a good solution. If I remove `?=foo` then the match will include everything to the end of the string.
How can I fix this regex to do the match the values after `>` as described?

Comment: What is your expected result? A list with 2 elements, `['key: >
   lorem ipsum 1213 __ ^123   
   lorem ipsum', 'anotherkey: >
   lorem ipsum 1213 __ ^123   
   lorem ipsum']`?

Comment: something like that, yes. I am using the pattern inside `re.findall`.

Comment: How about simply `^((?:[ \t].*\n?)+)*`. [See it here.](https://regex101.com/r/hP0aZ5/2)

Comment: Is the file small enough to process it as a multiline string?

Comment: I am working on a patch for markdown parser in Python, so I think most of time the file will be small enough.

Comment: @ClassG, your expression only matches the values.. I need the keys too.

Comment: Then use anubhava's solution. Or my enhanced version of it. Do not pay attention to steps, they just hint at performance, but do not really prove one regex superiority over another. However, unroll-the-loop is really a great technique.

Comment: Ahh... Got fooled by "captures all values after a key"  and "key to foo (excluding)" ;)

Comment: So something like `^(\w+):\s*>\n((?:[ \t].*\n?)+)*` would work then? [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hP0aZ5/3)

Comment: this already nicer. But the groups? Are they necessary? Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: @Oz123: See [`(?m)^(\w+):[ \t]*>((?:\n.*)?(?:\n(?!\w+:[ \t]*(?:>|\w+)\n).*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/uI8mR6/1) - are these the groups you need? Also,  see https://ideone.com/W8J3jL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As per request ;)

You could use something like

```
^\w+:\s*>\n(?:[ \t].*\n?)+
```

(This is without the groups. If you decide you wan't them, see the comments to the question.)

It matches the start of a line (`^`) followed by at least one word character (`\w` A-Z, a-z, 0-9 or '-'. Could be changed to `[a-z]` if only lower case alphas should be allowed).

Then it matches optional spaces (`\s*`) followed by the `>` *key-terminator* and a line feed (`\n`).

Then a non-capturing group (`(?:`) matching:

- a space or a tab
- followed by any character up to a line feed
- an optional line feed

This group (matching an indented line) can be repeated any number of times (but must exist at least once - `)+`).

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hP0aZ5/5).

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your regex to this:

```
(\w+:\s+>\n\s+[\S\s]+?)(?=\n\w+:\w+\n|\Z)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fU7wC3/1)

Lookahead `(?=\n\w+:\w+\n|\Z)` will assert presence of `key:value` or end of input (`\Z`) after your non-greedy match.

Alternatively this better performing regex can be used (thanks to Wiktor for the helpful comments below):

```
\w+:\s+>\n(.*(?:\n(?!\n\w+:\w+\n).*)+)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/fU7wC3/3)

Comment: Note that this "magic" (lazy pattern tempered with a positive lookahead with alternation inside) is costly, an unrolled version would be handy.

Comment: I replaced hardcoded lookahead `(?=foo)` with `(?=\n\w+:\w+\n|\Z)` which asserts presence of `key:value` line or end of input `\Z` after your non-greedy match.

Comment: [`(\w+:\s+>\n\s+(?:(?!\n\w+:\w+\n).)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fU7wC3/2) on regex101 takes 430 steps as compared to above lazy pattern that takes 423 steps, so not much difference.

Comment: @anubhava: a tempered greedy token does not present an unroll-the-loop technique. Here, [`\w+:[ \t]*>\n.*(?:\n(?!\w+:[ \t]*>\n).*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/zT2xZ6/1) - 70 steps. No DOTALL modifier can be used with this. However, to make it more precise, I'd add `^` at the pattern start and use `re.M`  flag - [`^\w+:[ \t]*>\n.*(?:\n(?!\w+:[ \t]*>\n).*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/zT2xZ6/2) (56 steps)

Comment: Well, not that great if there can be just one line in a block :) Perhaps, the first `\n.*` should be wrapped with an optional group - `(?:\n.*)?`

Comment: Just one problem that we have to exclude `foo:bar` from our matches.

Comment: It seems [`\w+:\s+>\n(.*(?:\n(?!\n\w+:\w+\n).*)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fU7wC3/3) will behave better

Comment: When there is no line breaks between consecutive blocks your [regex fails](https://regex101.com/r/fU7wC3/4) otherwise mine is [simplified version](https://regex101.com/r/eD0lW4/4) of yours.

Comment: Yes but OP just mentioned that **captures all values after a key followed by a > sign**, no where it mentioned that intention is to capture only lines that start with white-spaces.

Comment: Then take a look at title (*indentation*) and input string again.

Answer (score 0):

### One

If you are **not sure about indentations** whether or not they exist, then this is the *simplest* way you can achieve desired result:

```
^\w+:\s+>(?:\s?[^:]*$)*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/rM1qZ5/1)

Explanation:

```
^               # Start of line
\w+:\s+>        # Match specific block
(?:             # Start of non-capturing group (a)
    \s?             # Match a newline
    [^:]*$          # Match rest of line if only it doesn't have a :
)*              # End of non-capturing group (a) (zero or more times - greedy)
```

*You need `m` flag to be on as demonstrated in live demo.*

### Two - the simplest

If leading white-spaces are always there, then you can go with this safer regex:

```
^\w+:\s+>(?:\s?[\t ]+.*)*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD0lW4/3)

*`m` modifier should be set here as well.*